# Create a Shared Drive (formerly Team Drive) using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-workspace, google-drive-shared-drive

I am trying to ascertain if it possible to create a new Shared Drive (formerly "Team Drive") using Google Apps Script. I can see plenty examples of creating new folders inside an *already-existing* team drive, but not creating an entirely new drive.

I am hoping to be able to develop an Apps Script to create new team drives containing a pre-prepared structure of folders and documents, that individual teams can tailor to their own specific needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would have to use a `service-account.json` (for an account, which has oAuth2 scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`) in order to create a Team Drive through the [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/teamdrives/create). `App Script` itself does not feature methods to do that, but one can access just any `REST API` with [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app). once wrote a client called [CloudDatastore.gs](https://github.com/syslogic/google-apps-script/blob/master/cloud-datastore/CloudDatastore.gs), which should provide a good example of how it works, despite it's another API (and I don't intent to write such a drive client, unless being paid).

Comment: Since this answer was given, there is now a method to do this: insert.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done very straightforwardly using the Drive API method, [insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/drives/insert)

```
  Drive.Teamdrives.insert({name:"My New Team Drive"}, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000000000));
```

The second number simply has to be unique for each request to prevent multiple requests to make the same resource, and can even be entered manually.

Regarding the replication of a folder structure: There are multiple ways that can be achieved such as "hard-coding" in each folder creation, or something more complex which refers to a ready-made structure and deep-copies it, but I feel the question is answered in principle with the code snippet above.

Comment: Thanks for providing an updated method, which might simplify the processing.